# Binary is not optimized error for iPhone 5 - in Xcode6 with LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode 6 project that I can't upload, because I'm getting the

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 error New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image..

It's inconceivable why this happens, because I have a proper LaunchScreen.xib which should solve the launch image problem. The project is a native Xcode 6 project, I didn't migrated anything from Xcode 5, therefore I have no idea what could be the problem. Do anybody had the same problem? I checked the other related questions, but that issues happened with Xcode 5 projects.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your Deployment Target is set to iOS 7.1 or earlier then you still need the old style launch images. The launch screen file is only for iOS 8.

Comment: So I should create new image assets - launch images - for every devices, even for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus? Or just for the iPhone 5?

Comment: You need launch images for any device that may be running iOS 7 (or earlier if supported). Since the iPhone 6/6+ can't run iOS 7, you shouldn't need launch images for those devices.

Comment: It's just hilarious...but it's true

Comment: I have the same error with deployment target iOS 8. What's wrong on that case? stackoverflow.com/questions/27136053/…